# Rudin's PMA Theorem 7.9

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Here is rudin's statement

**Theorem 7.9** suppose
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=f(x)(x\in E).$$
Put
$$M_n=\sup_{x\in E}|f_n(x)-f(x)|.$$
Then $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $E$ if and only if $M_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Here is my question

Is the first condision unnecessary? Can I just point out ${f_n}$, $f$ and $x \in E$ instead?

Comment: It is not necessary.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy Thanks!